# IONIC ANGULAR - how can I modify the alert inside the ion-select?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, mobile

How can I achieve this kind of select:

[image]

Is there a way to modify the selected item?

[image]

I am new to ionic. I am aware of custom properties but none of it work as intended.
Tried the fake select where I used alert controller so I can modify as needed but doesn't suit the select options its more like an alert now instead of select

EDIT:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-select class="ion-no-border" placeholder="Select a Location" (ionChange)="searchByLocation($event); onLocationSelected($event)">
      <ion-label>Select a Location</ion-label>
      <ion-select-option [value]="data.locationName" *ngFor="let data of locations">
        {{ data.locationName }}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The doc's show how to do this:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#single-selection

Answer (score -1):

Setting interface to popover gives you the effect you are looking for:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-select interface="popover" placeholder="Select fruit">
      <ion-select-option value="apple">Apple</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="banana">Banana</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="orange">Orange</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```